# Is Rajiv Malhotra right in saying concepts of papa, atma, etc have no equivalent in other religions

Tags: sin

I was watching some video of Rajiv Malhotra, in it he said that Hindu concepts of Papa, Punya, Atma, etc are not same as soul, sin found in non-Hindu religions.

In English translations of Hindu scriptures, a Sanskrit word like papa or atma is translated as sin and soul, but the experiential network behind the meaning of those words might be completely different than the English words.

How appropriate is it to accuse or hold someone of having committed sin in Hinduism? When what we might call papa had completely different reasons than what the word sin means.

Comment: I am not sure your question has the right title. What kind of answer are you looking for here? You seem to be asking what I think is a very interesting question "How appropriate is it to accuse or hold someone of having committed sin in Hinduism [when the word sin comes from a different religious context]?" which might be a good answerable question, but your title says something else... Finally you ask about tags - that would be a question for [meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm new to this so I don't know all about it. Where to ask what?

Comment: Those videos you watched....did you hear the logic behind Rajiv Malhotra's argument?

Comment: Yes, I think I heard but I forgot.

Comment: Rajiv Malhotra I think is absolutely correct.These terms comes from specific spiritual thinking and culture and can not and shd not be translated without proper care.Please read Krishnaprem's wrirings to understand how a proper translation shd be.

Comment: @CounterView Do you want the logic behind Rajiv Malhotra's views as an answer?

Comment: Btw always use @ and then the username to ping somebody. Like whenever you're pinging me, use @Surya.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Okay. Thanks for this information. I learned this feature now and I'll use it in future conversations.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Yes I want his answers but also I'd want to know if it is appropriate to hold some guilty of sin, when that concept has issues with someone who has grown up in a Hindu society.

Comment: sin and soul can be used in hinduism as well albeit there is some difference in the concepts that you need to understand

Comment: Related: Similar thing discussed [meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240/277).