# What Hinduism says about the judgment day?

Tags: scripture

Are there any references to judgement day in Hinduism? 
Judgement Day, as per Abrahmanic religion refer to the day when the earth is destroyed. Everyone will be resurrected to be judged about what they did on earth.

Is there anything like this in Hindu scripture?

Comment: No, there is no judgement day in Hindu scripture.

Comment: not a question on Hinduism.

Comment: No there is nothing alike in Hinduism but there is something similar. The Kalki avatar will bring about the start of a new yuga.

Comment: A simple yes/no answer would have suffice. Why close the question?

Comment: Do you want to be Judged ? Propagate that question to all up the chain and down the chain. Expand it to all living things, self-aware entities, non-things, earth, Sun, Sky etc., pose the question to the Supreme Being. Pose the question to Parabrahman. Whomsoever answers decides the judgement for that being and entities under him or HIM as the case may be...and the day that happens becomes the Judgement Day. Yes such a concept exists in Hinduism. And the result depends on the Judgement :-). Bad verdict for earth for e.g. results in Pralaya or Destruction.

Comment: Who indeed are the prosecutors, the defending lawyers? Where indeed is the court Room or a Phantom court? Who is the Jury? Who is the Judge? Can the Judge be Judged? Where do you draw the Line? Who draws the Line? Precisely. It's Complicated. Go with A relieving thought that there are Blemishless ones Above All levels including ParahBrahman :-) who can judge fair. The guarantee is  you will find a Judge :-)  --Nasadya Sukta

Answer (score 3):

There is no concept of judgment day in Hindu scriptures. Jeeva or individual soul goes through the process of repeated births and deaths till it attains liberation or moksha.

Refer [What is the life cycle of a soul (atma) in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3568/)

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Not that you should cite some sources while answering questions. I have added link to one  from this site for time being.