# What is the (potentially lost) text of the Jabalas quoted by Adi Shankaracharya?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, upanishads, adi-shankaracharya, brahma-sutras

In his commentary on Adhyaya 4 Pada 1 Sutra 3 of the Brahma Sutras, Adi Shankaracharya presents a number of scriptural quotes to support his Advaita view that the individual soul of jivatma is the same as Brahman.  In particular, he says [this](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38264.htm):

> The highest Lord must be understood as the Self. For in a chapter treating of the highest Lord the Gâbâlas acknowledge him to be the Self, **'Thou indeed I am. O holy divinity; I indeed thou art, O divinity!'**

My question is, what is the text of "the Jabalas" that is quoted here?  I assume the Jabalas were a Vedic Shakha or school related the sage Jabili, who tried to use atheist arguments to convince Rama to come back to Ayodhya, as [described](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga108/ayodhya_108_frame.htm) in the Ayodhya Kanda of the Ramayana.  (See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6807/36) for more information on Vedic Shakhas.)

Now there is an Upanishad called the Jabala Upsnishad, which you can read [here](http://www.vedarahasya.net/jabala.htm), and a Shaivite Upanishad called the Brihadjabala Upanishad, which you can read [here](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/vedicsection/upanishads/brihadjabala.asp), but neither one of them contain the verse I'm looking for.

I did find the verse in a Vaishnava Upanishad called the Varaha Upanishad, which you can read [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/tmu/tmu29.htm):

> Prostrations—prostrations to me who am in all the elements, who am the Chiḍāṭmā (viz., Āṭmā of the nature of wisdom) that is eternal and free and who am the Praṭyagāṭmā. **O Ḍevaṭā, you are I. I am you.** Prostrations on account of myself and yourself who are infinite and who are Chiḍāṭmā, myself being the supreme Īśa (Lord) and yourself being Śiva (of a beneficent nature).

But it's unlikely this is the text that Adi Shankaracharya was quoting from, since it has nothing to with the Jabalas.  The Varaha Upanishad may be quoting some older text here.

I should add that this verse is also quoted in Adi Shankacharya's commentary on the Vishnu Sahasranamam, Vidyaranya's work the Brahmavid-Ashirvada, and Ramanujacharya's commentary on the Brahma Sutras (see [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48500.htm)).  If it helps, here is the verse in Sanskrit:

> tvaṁ vā ahamasmi bhagavō dēvatē'haṁ vai tvamasi

Comment: The verse is 4.1.3 not 4.1.4....

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda OK, I corrected it.  So do you have any idea what this text of the Jabalas is?

Comment: In the Sri Bhasya Ramanuja calls them ancient meditators. The only reference I can find is here that calls it a school of the Yajur veda - http://www.oldict.com/jabala/

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda In the translation of the Sri Bhashya I'm using he calls them "the great Devotees of olden times".  I'm not sure what the Sanskrit term Ramanujacharya uses is.  By the way, Vidyaranya calls the text a Shruti of the Jabalas.  But yeah, I do think the Jabalas were a Vedic school.  I just hope that the text in question is some Upanishad or other Vedic text that still exists.

Comment: I've found same verse written in [Brahmavid-Ashirvada](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_major_works/brahmavidashirvada.html?lang=sa) but it is composed by [Vidyaranya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidyaranya).

Comment: @Pandya Yes, as I said in my comment [above](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7612/what-is-the-potentially-lost-text-of-the-jabalas-quoted-by-adi-shankaracharya?noredirect=1#comment15815_7612), Vidyaranya quotes it saying that it's a "Shruti of the Jabalas".

Comment: Adi Shankarachraya also mentioned it in Adhyaya 3, Pada 3, Sutra 37.