# Which are those 400 words of Veda not known or understood to even Yaska?

Tags: vedas, etymology, yaska

[Nirukta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirukta) is one of six [Vedangas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanga) which are very essential to completely understanding Vedas. Nirukta is the study of the origin of Sanskrit words i.e etymology which is very useful for understanding and interpreting Sanskrit words.

Now, when I was reading the preface of Rigveda by Gayatri Pariwar, I found the following line (you can read it online at [Awgp Literature](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v1.10):

> [image]

The English translation (meaning) of the line underlined is:

> Even **Niruktakara Yaska mentioned/counted around 400 words of Vedas of which meaning is not known to him**

I want to know which are those 400 words whose meaning is not known/understood to even Niruktakara Yaskacharya? (Is there a list of those 400 words available?)

Comment: Related [Where are the indecipherable Puranic verses discussed by Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11418/5212)

Comment: Good luck on this interesting question. You might have to set a bounty for something so esoteric. That said, I'm going to try my Google-fu.

Comment: Good question.  However,  only a Sage can answer this question.   Yaska was only a scholar and thus could not understand the words used by composers of Veda, who were sages by themselves. @Pandya

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Thanks. I am just asking to enlist those words not asking for meaning of them.

Comment: Does this author cite any sources for his statement? I have studied Niruktam many times, and there is no list by Yaska saying he doesn't know the meanings of 400 words. He actually thoroughly expounds the etymology of words from the Nighantu, and does it very systematically.

Comment: This question **MIGHT** be already Questioned and answered [HERE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33159/are-some-of-the-words-from-vedas-still-untranslatable)

Comment: This is a wonderful question! Wanted to add that [Vedic substratum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substratum_in_Vedic_Sanskrit) that indologists speak of, but the meaning of these words is certainly known.