# Does Karma of parents affect their children?

Tags: karma, parents, children

I would like to know if the Karma of parents has any effect on their children?

Or are they independent and have to realize their own Karma (prārabdha/sañcita)?

Comment: no, karma of parents does not effect children or anyone, everyone has to do their own karma to decide their destiny.

Comment: Most of the karma that one has is his own, but in some cases it is possible to get some of the karma of the parents. There are some examples of this in the scriptures. See below one such example in the answer by Keshav Srinivasan.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, the Karma of parents does affect their children.**. Here is what Brihaspati's brother Uchathya tells Vishnu's incarnation Mandhata (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7221/36)) in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a090.htm) of the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata:

> The tears shed by weeping men afflicted with falsehood slay the children and animals of those that have uttered those falsehoods. Like a cow a sinful act perpetrated does not produce immediate fruits.  If the fruit is not seen in the perpetrator himself, it is seen in his son or in his son's son, or daughter's son.

But to that I would put one qualification: the family that you are born into is ultimately determined by your actions in past births, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2049/36).  So even if you are punished for your parents' sin, the punishment you experience may also be due to the actions you did in past births that made you be born into that family in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Namaste

Children are born a couple based on the combined net effect of their karma. It is said in jyotisha sastra that the happening (often bad if any) child's first four years are result of mother's own karma, the next four years that of father's, the next four years of that individual.

Children can give and take life of their parents i.e. children born on amavasya when Moon is merged in sun, indicates, loss of maternal love & affection, hence considered to be a bad omen by some.  Similarly children  in purnima when sun & moon are bright reflects parents affection in plenty.

Moon represents mother, Sun represents father.  If either of them afflicted then that karaka suffers, say like a child born during eclipse, depending it lunar or solar eclipse, one would suffer for Rahu would be in close degrees with Moon/Sun. Rahu = shadow

Every individual brings his own fate & destiny.  It is a beauty of nature's law that using jyotisha sastra, with one horrorscope, presuming the jyotish is a learned one, one can predict three generations before & after ... i.e. one can predict on father/mother, grandfather/grandmother, children & grand children, prosperity of brothers/sisters.

Devaki-Vasudev prayed and got children, seven got killed by Kamsa, eight child survived (Lord Krishna) who gave moksha to his parents.  However, the first seven children brought grief & sorrow to their parents.

Every soul of an animate or inanimate, has its own individual karma, plus its family karma (Bhagirath who brought goddess mother ganga to mother earth), community karma & state, country karma

Person born in America enjoys better privileges than an African born = country karma.  Similarly extend it for other segments too.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "yes" and "no." A more descriptive "short" answer is that the *karma* of the parents in their past life affects the *karma* of the child, but the *karma* of the parents in the current life does not.

We are linked by *karma* to everyone else in the world, because the actions and abilities of others do, quite obviously and factually, affect us. When the *jīva* takes a body as the child of a certain set of parents, it is not randomly. Because the parents' *karma* determines their place in life, and that situation in life will affect the upbringing of the child and the child's current and future actions, behavior, attitude, conduct, and life situation, the child's *karma*  is affected by the parents' karma in their past life--their "karmic debt" is affected by their place in life and their sufferings as a result of their parents' place in life. This is simply a logical deduction. If, of course, you have any objections to this, feel free to let me know, because I know this may be imperfect in several ways.

Wendy Doniger (controversial, I know) says in her book *On Hinduism* on page 104  (this book wasn't the one that was banned):

> ...the transmigrating soul is said to mix its own inherited karma with the karma of each of the new parents to form the cumulative karma of the new child.

To support this statement, she gives a reference to some other work or maybe even Hindu scripture in the endnotes--however, I am unable to access the reference because I could only obtain a preview from Google Books. I encourage anyone with the full version to leave a comment informing me of the reference.

However, what the parents do in the current life **does not** affect the *karma* of the child in the current life, except by indirect means (if the parents instill bad values in the child by setting a bad example, the child may commit wrongdoing later in life). But a theft, for example, by one of the parents will not affect the child. There is no reason to think it would. Philosophically, it creates some extremely obvious problems. As far as I know (and there's a really good chance I might be wrong here), the scriptures doesn't explicitly deny this idea, but see *Bhagavadgītā* 5.13:

> *sarvakarmāṇi manasā sannyasyāste sukhaṃ vaśī* |
>   *navadvāre pure dehī naiva kurvanna kārayan*

This may be translated very, very literally as:

> Having [completely] forsaken all actions mentally, that which is embodied [*i.e.*, the soul] happily remains one who has control (*i.e.*, the controller)  in the city of nine gates (*i.e.*, the body), not doing, not causing [anyone] to do [anything].

Now if renunciation means that the soul becomes the controller, and no action will take place, then the parents' current actions cannot affect the child's current *karma*. Otherwise, religious renunciation could take place, but the soul would not become the controller and it could not be said to be in true "inaction" (as described in this verse) because it still would be accumulating *karma*. Thus, the parents' *karma* in the current life does not affect the child's *karma* unless the child chooses to follow in the steps of the parents and commit some crime.

Comment: Doniger cites "Doniger O'Flaherty, 'Karma and Rebirth'."  Now I assume that's a reference to her book "Karma and Rebirth in Classical Indian Traditions".  It's a collection of essays by different authors, but the only essay written by Doniger herself is "Karma and Rebirth in the Vedas and Puranas", so I assume that's where the information comes from.  Here's the essay: http://gdurl.com/q3nJ

Comment: But concerning your idea about the karma of our parents' past births affecting us, I think that's backwards.  Your past karma determines what set of parents you'll be born to; see my answer here, where I quote from the Garuda Purana: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2049/36 "The righteous man having enjoyed heaven, is born in a stainless family."  So it's not like you'll accidentally be born into a family that's in a better or worse situation than what your own past karma would dictate.

Comment: So you can't say "If my parents had committed more sins in their previous birth, my life would be worse off now."  No, if your parents had committed more sins in their previous birth, you would have been born to a different set of parents.  So your parents' deeds in a past birth have no causal influence on what happens to you.

Comment: "Thus, the parents' karma in the current life does not affect the child's karma unless the child chooses to follow in the steps of the parents and commit some crime."  I don't see how that follows at all.  Assuming your argument is valid, all it says is that a person who practices renunciation does not incur any effects of karma generated by his parents.  But what about those who don't follow renunciation, but still don't follow in the steps of their parents in committing crimes?  How does your argument demonstrate that such people are unaffected when their parents commit an act of theft?

Comment: Hmm...I wasn't thinking about how even your birth  situation will be decided by karma. But also then how is it possible that it seems that some good children have bad parents and vice versa? Now with regard to the last comment, what I was trying to say was that if controlling your own actions with your own mind is enough to avoid accumulating karma, then even those who don't practice renunciation will only accumulate karma from themselves. Otherwise, those who do practice renunciation wouldn't be able to avoid accumulating karma from the parents. I don't know if that makes more sense now.

Comment: "But also then how is it possible that it seems that some good children have bad parents and vice versa?"  That's a species of a more general question, "Why do good things happen to bad people and bad things happen to good people?"  The answer is "They did something to deserve it, either in this birth or in some previous birth." You may be a good person now, but perhaps ten births ago you committed some great sin that leads you to be born to bad parents. That's the thing about karma, you don't know when it will bear fruit. Sometimes it bears fruit instantly, sometimes numerous births from now.

Comment: "Now with regard to the last comment, what I was trying to say was that if controlling your own actions with your own mind is enough to avoid accumulating karma, then even those who don't practice renunciation will only accumulate karma from themselves."  Well, what do you mean by "controlling your own actions with your own mind"?  Do you mean what the Gita verse is talking about, i.e. self-restraint of the senses as a part of renunciation?  If that's what you mean I don't see how "then even those who don't practice renunciation will only accumulate karma from themselves" follows from that.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Yes, the verse says "giving up all actions with the mind." So what I'm saying is that if the verse says that having given up all actions, one can be without accumulating karma. If the parents' karma did affect one, however, it would not be sufficient to simply give up one's own actions to avoid accumulating karma.

Comment: "If the parents' karma did affect one, however, it would not be sufficient to simply give up one's own actions to avoid accumulating karma."  Why not?  What if giving up one's own actions cut off all accumulation of karma for you, either caused by yourself or caused by others? The act of surrender involves seeking refuge in Vishnu, so that Vishnu can stop the accumulation of karma.  He can equally well stop the accumulation of karma caused by you or caused by others if he so chooses.  So I don't see how your argument works.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Yeah, that's true, and actually I had thought of that, but I didn't think the verse referring to complete surrender to Ishwara. So do you think that parents' karma does get transferred to the child then?

Comment: I'm actually not sure whether parents' karma gets transferred to children, I just didn't think your arguments involving renunciation made sense.  Intuitively I'd assume that it doesn't usually get transferred, but I think there may be cases where all the descendants of someone suffer some curse because of what one of their ancestors did, and a similarly in the case of a blessing.

Comment: By the way, since you're a Dvaitin you may be interested in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7770/36

Comment: The karmas of parents is said to impact the children too. This is like property of parents are inherited by children, similarly, the impacts of good and bad karma of parents tend to impact their children. Even after surrender to Lord, the prarabdha karma has to endured. What is generally told is that remaining karma, Good and Bad karmas are transferred to well wishers and enemies of the Jiva respectively, before the Jiva gets liberated.

Comment: @Krishna "The karmas of parents is said to impact the children too. This is like property of parents are inherited by children, similarly, the impacts of good and bad karma of parents tend to impact their children."  What scripture says that?

Comment: @Keshav - I heard this in one of the pgms by a srivaishnava scholar.

Answer (score 2):

A child is affected by his parents Karma so does the parents by child's karmas.
It is their Prarabdha which bring them together as a family and therefore, the results of their respective karma are affecting others.
A Prarabdha is defined as the collection of Karmas whose fruits are supposed to be bore by a given soul in upcoming life.
A Prarabdha is decided before the body is been assigned to a soul. Therefore, there is absolutely no chance for a soul to escape from these Prarabdhas.
Close to 70% of our life is affected by this Prarabdha.

A science behind Karma is very complex and subtle to be understood by a common man. Therefore, the best option is to continue doing good karmas.